# Registering static UI element events with Backbone View component

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am simply trying to implement `click` on a button without using `template`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="transfer">
            <input type="text" placeholder="From Address" id="fromAddress" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="To Address" id="toAddress" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Amount" id="amount" />
            <input type="button" id="transferMoney" value="Transfer"/>
        </div>
```

**Backbone View**

```
var TransferView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click #transferMoney": "sendMoney"
    },
    sendMoney: function() {
        alert();
        console.log($("#fromAddress").val());
        //this.modeltransferMoney);
    }
});

var transferView = new TransferView({mdoel: transferMoney});
transferView.render();
```

But `sendMoney()` does not get called when I click on `#transferMoney` button. 
Do I always have to create button using `template`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the events hash is limited in scope to the view (see http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents). Try

```
var TransferView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        $("#transferMoney").on("click", this.sendMoney);
    },
    sendMoney: function() {
        alert();
        console.log($("#fromAddress").val());
        //this.modeltransferMoney);
    }
});

var transferView = new TransferView({mdoel: transferMoney});
transferView.render();
```